# How can I align the first row of these equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\nu = \rho \cdot \eta
\end{equation}
some text
\begin{flalign}
\text{Grenzviskosität} && [\eta] =&\lim\limits_{c,G \rightarrow \infty}{\eta_{red}} &\\
\text{reduzierte Viskosität} && \eta_{red} =& \frac{\eta_{sp}}{c}\\
\text{spezifische Viskosität} && \eta_{sp} =&\frac{\eta - \eta_{L}}{\eta_{L}} 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

I want the first equation to be aligned with the second block

Answer (score 5):

Put  `&` before the text, not after. I also modified text subscripts (red, sp) as text, and removed `\limits` (redundant in this environment) in the first equation:

```
 \documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 &\text{Grenzviskosität}& [\eta] &=\lim_{c,G \rightarrow \infty}{\eta_\text{red}} & \\
&\text{reduzierte Viskosität}& \eta_\text{red} &= \frac{\eta_{sp}}{c}\\
 &\text{spezifische Viskosität}& \eta_\text{sp} &=\frac{\eta - \eta_{L}}{\eta_{L}}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]